# What is law of random variable $ S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n $

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We consider a sequence $ (X_n)_{n \leq 1} $ of mutually independent random variables defined on a probability space $ (\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P}) $  with value in $\{-1,1\}$ and such that, for all $ k \geq 1$ $$ \mathbb{P} (X_k = -1) = \mathbb{P} (X_k = 1) = \frac{1}{2} $$ For all $ n \geq 1 $, we set $ S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n $

**Problem**

What is law of random  variable $S_n$?

An idea please.

Comment: $X= 2Y-1$ where $Y$ has the distribution $P(Y=0)=P(Y=1)=\frac{1}{2}.$ The distribution of the sum of $Y$'s is well-known.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring order, all drawings with $p$ positives are equiprobable with probability $\dfrac1{2^p}\dfrac1{2^{n-p}}=\dfrac1{2^n}$, and the values sum to $p-(n-p)=2p-n$. Observe that all sums are distinct, hence a function of $p$.

Now if we restore order, the $p$ positives can appear in $\displaystyle\binom np$ different ways, and this gives us the distribution:

$$\mathbb P(S_n=2p-n)=\binom np\frac1{2^n}$$ for $p=0,1,\cdots n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The Count for values of $+1$ among the sequence of ${(X_k)}_{k=1}^n$ shall be the count for successes among $n$ independent Bernoulli trials with an identical success rate.